# Future and latency: How to prioritize the execution of some Futures over the others

Tags: scala, concurrency, executorservice

I have a Akka/Spray.io REST server which, upon receiving request from a user, will perform three operations for the said user:

1. uploads user data to remote storage.
2. update user stats in the DB
3. respond to the user indicating whether the operation fails or succeeds

As they're all blocking operations by nature, they are wrapped in `scala.concurrent.Future` for asynchronous execution.

The problem I'm facing is that the server's response latency is very high (5 seconds) when under heavy load. Upon investigation, the problem is due to the fact that the `Future` instance containing a response for a particular user isn't executed as soon as the computation for that user is finished. Rather I often find them queued way behind other tasks.

This is basically a prioritization problem. Ideally the server so continue performing asynchronous operations, but when a user response is available, it should prioritize it above other tasks. Imagine that we can say to the server, "Hey, I know you'll have many pending requests from other users, but since you've finished updating DB and uploading data for this particular user, why not response to the user first before continuing to serve other clients"

I've tried is to set up two ExecutionContext instances, `responseEC`, a dedicated `ExecutionContext` for sending user response and `generalBlockingEC` for other (blocking) tasks. I expected that JVM will alternate the execution between the two EC instances with a high degree of fairness and see my response being sent in a more timely approach.

Unfortunately, for some reason JVM is biased to spend more time in `generalBlockingEC` instead of working alternatively between `responseEC` and `generalBlockingEC` in a fair manner.

Am I approaching the problem the wrong way? Are there better ways to prioritize the execution of some `Future` instances over the others (e.g. maybe with the help of Actor)?

Comment: Why do you run all those things in parallel? If for example one fails and the other succeed you would still return a failure to the user but with the disadvantage of having wasted a thread on an operation, also note that even though you wrap them in futures, they are still blocking the assigned thread as far as I know.

Comment: @EndeNeu when a blocking call is encountered within a thread, context switch will be performed so another thread can execute. context switch is expensive but when tuned correctly (by taking into account number of available CPU and average blocking time amongst others), the speed benefit of multi-threading several blocking calls will still outweigh the cost of context switches

Answer (score 3):

First of all I will defer to the answer here on why there is not a mechanism to prioritise some thread pools over others: [How to configure ThreadPool priority in Playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087783/how-to-configure-threadpool-priority-in-playframework) Specifically:

> There is currently no way to configure thread priority because that
>   setting is mostly without effect on many platforms and as such
>   qualifies as a placebo. If you start and actively use more threads
>   than you have CPU cores then the resulting competition will be costly
>   and will waste resources, so you will be better off carefully fitting
>   your threadpool sizes to the available cores for the CPU-bound part.

I think you have started down the right lines by creating two execution contexts. I recommend you ensure that each execution context has its own Threadpool and that the total number of threads between the two does not exceed, or does not significantly exceed, the number of cores on the hardware.

If you want to favour one execution context over the other, you could try giving it a greater proportion of the total number of threads.

Comment: Interesting. So how should one strives for a relatively consistent latency profile in the application if the basic building blocks provides little guarantee of such things? Maybe its just me but I feel tuning thread count is quite fiddly and isn't a very robust solution in general

Comment: Scaling out to multiple machines?